# How to get a reply to a Trademark Issue from Twitter Support?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to have a certain unused Twitter username. The name is one of the trade names of my company. I reported a Trademark Issue via Twitter's form three weeks ago, but nothing has happened since.

I just replied to the ticket, maybe they'll notice it this time. Furthermore I submitted the issue again and sent a fax to the number they provided for additional legal information, asking for a reply. Lastly I mentioned some Twitter Support employees on their personal account asking for a reply.

Does anybody have experiences with Twitter Support in cases like these?

Comment: One of the Twitter Support employees replied to the new issue I submitted yesterday. It's "transferred (…) to the appropriate team for investigation". Let's hope I'll hear from them soon.

Comment: I can't believe it, but I just got a reply from a Twitter Trust & Safety employee. He needed some information about my trademark registration (which I already provided when I opened the claim). I just replied and provided the information. Let's hope he can fix it :)

Comment: Just got another reply from the Twitter Trust & Safety employee. I was asked to make a temporary account, which will get the username I requested. It might work in the end!